# How to define methods inside of Plugin in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin, class, methods

I try to overwrite **get_url()** function located in **item.php** from this path **\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php**

For this, i created a PLUGIN, and my code it's this one:

```
<?php

namespace mysite\CartNotification\Plugin;

class CategoryPlugin {


    public function aftergetUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item $item)
        {
            //this code change the category links name to a freandly SEO Llinks
            if($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() =="cat"){

                $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $object_manager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($this->getValue())->getUrl();
                $return = $object_manager;

                $request = $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);

                if(strpos($request,'?') !== false ){
                    $query_string = substr($request,strpos($request,'?'));
                }
                else{
                    $query_string = '';
                }
                if(!empty($query_string)){
                    $return .= $query_string;
                }
                return $return;
            }
            else{

                $query = [
                $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() => $this->getValue(),
                // exclude current page from urls
                $this->_htmlPagerBlock->getPageVarName() => null,
                ];

                 return $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $query]);

                }

        }
}
```

But i have an issue with the methods that are used in this file.
When i run this code, i get err for each methods used here with this message:  **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Sitename\CartNotification\Plugin\CategoryPlugin::getFilter() in...**

So my funciton are not define. Does anyone know how to solve this problem. and define my methods?

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

```
$item->getFilter()
```

instead of :

```
$this->getFilter()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
class CategoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * Url
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
    ) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function afterGetUrl(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item $item,
        $resultUrl
    ) {
        //this code change the category links name to a freandly SEO Llinks
        if($item->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == "cat") {

            $return = $this->category->load($item->getValue())->getUrl();
            $request = $this->url->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);

            if(strpos($request,'?') !== false ) {
                $query_string = substr($request,strpos($request,'?'));
            } else {
                $query_string = '';
            }

            if(!empty($query_string)) {
                $return .= $query_string;
            }

            return $return;
        }

        return $resultUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know why this it's working just for the first category? i mean, now all my category have the same name like the first one

Comment: but if a insert only the function in vendor location, this works just fine